# some problem about initContainer for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have two containers，maybe A and B, which A should run before B, but A is a server application, which the final type is Running but not Complete, so I wonder in this way, will B be never executed? So how can I deal with it?

Comment: Hi edselwang, can you clarify what you mean by "A should run before B?" Should A start before B? Should A run for several seconds before B? Should A finish executing before B starts?

Comment: Do you mean B is deponds on A, so it has to be started after A is functional ready? InitContainer is not the right choice, maybe you can take a look at [pod liveness/readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).

Comment: I mean that A should run for several seconds before B， because A is a server application so that the final type of A is Running，not Completed，maybe readiness probe is the answer for my question， I will try it latter.

Answer (score 3):

If A and B are part of the same pod, then [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) is the legacy way to establish ordering.

From the [Kubernetes Pod lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states), I suppose you mean "Running, but no Terminated"

A [pod liveness/readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) is in your case a better fit, since the server will not accept request until ready.

Read "[Straight to the Point: Kubernetes Probes](https://medium.com/faun/straight-to-the-point-kubernetes-probes-e5b23e267d9d)" from [Peter Malina](https://twitter.com/petomalina)

> Both readiness and liveness probe run in parallel throughout the life of a container.
>
> - Use the liveness probe to detect an internal failure and restart the container (e.g. HTTP server down).
> - Use the readiness probe to detect if you can serve traffic (e.g. established DB connection) and wait (not restart) for the container.
>
> A dead container is also not a ready container.
>   To serve traffic, all containers within a pod must be ready.

You can add a [pod readiness gate (stable from 1.14)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-readiness-gate) to specify additional conditions to be evaluated for Pod readiness.

Read also "[Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes: How to Avoid Shooting Yourself in the Foot](https://blog.colinbreck.com/kubernetes-liveness-and-readiness-probes-how-to-avoid-shooting-yourself-in-the-foot/)" from [Colin Breck](https://blog.colinbreck.com/)

"[Should Health Checks call other App Health Checks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53874319/6309)" compares that approach with the [InitContainer approach](https://medium.com/@xcoulon/initializing-containers-in-order-with-kubernetes-18173b9cc222)